# Magento 2.2/2.3 and varnish 6

Tags: magento2, varnish

Has Magento 2 supported varnish 6?

Have anyone tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Magento 2.2 no but Magento 2.3.3 yes

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/release-notes-2-3-3-open-source.html

Answer (score 0):

No, for more details pleease visit this link : 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0CE.html